# Full Calendar Failed to Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I dont know the problem why my full calendar won't appear? Here's the error.

[image]

Comment: your console have some error? So put your code and error both here

Comment: Code would be helpful for sure here...unclear otherwise.

Comment: I guess, your XHR call is returing a `html` response instead of `json`, Please check whether you have set the correct `content-type` in the response header.

Comment: Should i copy the index.php code? or what file should i copy here? cause i dont have any idea wheres the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `json_events` value is already coming in `JSON` format. Why would you need to parse it?. Can you remove the JSON.parse and try using just

```
events: json_events,
```

Hope this helps.